# Merge image with a video with nreco

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have converted an image in to a vedio using following code

```
NReco.VideoConverter.ConvertSettings setting = new NReco.VideoConverter.ConvertSettings();
            setting.SetVideoFrameSize(FrameSizeWidth, FrameSizeHeight);
            setting.VideoCodec = "libx264";
            setting.AudioCodec = "mp3";
            setting.CustomInputArgs = " -framerate 1/"+imageDuration;
            setting.CustomOutputArgs = " -profile:v high -r 30";

                FFMpegConv.ConvertMedia(inputFilePath, null, outputFIlePath, null, setting);
```

And also I have a mp4 video with me which is splited using the follwoing code.

```
var ffMpegConverter = new FFMpegConverter();
            ffMpegConverter.ConvertMedia(SourceFile, Format.mp4, DestinationFile, Format.mp4,
                new ConvertSettings()
                {
                    Seek = StartTime,
                    MaxDuration = (EndTime-StartTime),
                    VideoCodec = "libx264",
                    AudioCodec = "mp3",
                });
```

I need to concat these two videos. I used the fllowing code for it.Here the SourceVideoList array contains the two videos(Splite and image video)

```
var ffMpegConverter = new FFMpegConverter();
            ffMpegConverter.ConcatMedia(SourceVideoList.ToArray(),OutputFile,null,new ConcatSettings());
```

But when i try to do it gives and error saying "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0".
Can some one help me on this

Answer (score 1):

ConcatMedia method uses ffmpeg concat filter; it expects that all input video chunks have the same frame size and frame rate. In most cases error you faced (Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0) means that video chunks have incompatible set of parameters. You can get more information by handling LogReceived event (to get ffmpeg console log output).

Note that you can use another ways to merge videos supported by ffmpeg (concat demuxer, concat protocol - see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate for more details) with ConvertMedia method overload that accepts several input files.

Comment: Hi i was able to concat the two methods using ffmpeg tool using the following argument

`ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

But when i try to concat the same two videos with nreco it give me above error. Can you expalin me how i can pass these same argument in to nreco custom atrguments.